# How to achieve this Blue shape effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gradient, abstract

[image: Baugasm]

Can someone help me understand how to achieve this **Blue curve** in this picture with the help of **Adobe Photoshop**? I tried layer masks but it's not exactly giving me this effect. Also, how was the **highlight** added to it?

Comment: Looks suspiciously like something that has been created in a 3D package and then combined with the image. Certainly achievable using just Photoshop though. Do you need to EXACTLY copy this or do you just want something that looks similar?

Comment: I disagree with Chris.  I think this was just painted by hand. Use soft brushes, play around with blurring/smudging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with mask, brush and dodge brush.

First create a circle mask and refine edge, add some feather.
[image]

Next, paint with indigo blue, use a brush with softness to 0. You can also add some blur to spread the color.
[image]

And last, use the dodge tool. Remember, you have to unchek the "protect tones" checkbox.
[image][image]

Good luck!